# Webpack combining multiple dynamic imports with different webpackExports into 1 chunk

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-5

Using Webpack 5, in one entry file I have multiple dynamic imports setup like so: `import(/* webpackExports: ["moduleName"] */ 'package name');` each of these imports are done under different conditions. Likely on a page load only one of the 5 or so imports should actually be called. These imports are spread over multiple different packages.

The problem is for some reason Webpack is setting all these imports into one, rather larger, chunk instead of individual chunks as I would expect them to be.

Just to make sure there wasn't some cross dependency conflict or something I tried clearing the imported modules out to be practically nothing for testing purposes. I've also tried using webpackChunkName. Nothing has worked.

Why would webpack be making these one chunk instead of multiple? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to "state". Conditional loading does not mean that we can have multiple states for the same module. Issues with side effects and live bindings force webpack (or any loader) to aggregate all the exports of a module that are being used, conditionally or not, into one chunk.

Therefore, it's a limitation with tree shaking of dynamically imported modules.

I have written more about this here: https://blog.hotstar.com/how-to-dynamically-import-esmodules-and-tree-shake-them-too-aa24ee4885f5